# iPhone: NSTimer stops temporarily when a touch action is performed?

Tags: iphone, image, event-handling, progress-bar

I am developing an iOS application where I trigger the NSTimer repeatedly for every 0.5 seconds and based on that timer I move a song progress bar. I handle touch events when the user touches on some images, which I keep in the same view.

However, when the user touches the images, the timer for moving the progress bar stops temporarily and continues again. Are there any problems that we should cater for when wanting to  handle the timer and touch events at the same time in the same view?

Is there a reason for the temporary stoppage when touching the images?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like there is too much going on on the main thread of the app.  The timer method calls are delivered on the main run loop as are the touch events.  Make sure that neither your touch event handler nor your timer handlers are doing any serious computational or IO work on the main thread.

In working with the highest level audio framework in iOS (AVPlayer) it only updates the current position in the audio track once a second.  So, maybe having the timer call every 0.5 seconds is overkill, maybe every 1 or 0.9 seconds would reduce the contention a bit.